# How do they do the Google Maps on-scroll filter in AirBnb

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps

If you click [here](https://www.airbnb.co.in/s/Paris--France?checkin=19-10-2015&checkout=22-10-2015&guests=&ne_lat=48.919775552436384&ne_lng=2.421713922144022&search_by_map=true&source=bb&ss_id=igc79w6m&ss_preload=false&sw_lat=48.807169602913845&sw_lng=2.2479926086674595&zoom=12) and goto the Search page in AirBnb, you will see that if you zoom in or zoom out the map on the right side of the page, The search results are updated based on the area that is displayed on the map.

I find this an amazing feature. But, I have no idea how they are doing it. Can anyone throw some light on how it can be done?

Comment: they probably have event listeners for when the map zoom changes.  And when that happens, they then most likely are doing an AJAX request to get properties within the currently visible bounds.  Server-side it's probably doing a location-based SQL query to get those properties. Which bit are you needing light thrown on?

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but the thing I don't understand is How do they know the Exact distance rectangle(or radius) within which they are limiting the search results?? I hope u can understand my query

Comment: Does Google maps api have a service for that??

Comment: They have the Geometry library, which has functions like computeLength and computeArea. See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. So, if I were to recreate something like this, I need to study the JavaScript API of Google Maps?? Also, I believe the overlays that they are showing there can also be done via. this, Am i right?? @duncan

Comment: @duncan Can you kindly look into this problem that I am in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33493334/display-markers-which-are-within-the-current-view-port-in-google-maps-v3-js-api